# Project a Right Angle (rightangle) with pst-solides3d Problems

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I'm attempting to add a right angle to my diagram, and have looked at all the help that I can find including the manual and several topics on stackexchange, but I just can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using TeXworks with XeLaTeX. I will be drawing several prisms, not all right triangle bases, so I will also need to project a dashed line to show the base triangle height on acute triangles and two dashed lines for obtuse triangles. If I can get the rightangle mark to work, perhaps the dashed line will be a cinch?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, output-decimal-marker = {.}, group-digits=integer}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,6)
\psset{viewpoint=-50 -80 30, Decran=100} 
\psSolid[object=prisme, base= 0 0 4.5 0 0 3.8, h=1.5, action=draw*, fillcolor=Red!20, name=theprism] 
\psPoint(0,0,0){b1}
\psPoint(4.5,0,0){b2}
\psPoint(0,3.8,0){b3}
\psPoint(0,0,1.5){h1}
\psPoint(4.5,0,1.5){h2}
\psPoint(0,3.8,1.5){h3}
\pcline[linestyle=none](b1)(b2)
\nbput[nrot=:U]{\num{4.5} cm}
\pcline[linestyle=none](b3)(b1)
\nbput[nrot=:U]{\num{3.8} cm}
\pcline[linestyle=none](h3)(h2)
\naput[nrot=:U]{\num{5.9} cm}
\pcline[linestyle=none](b2)(h2)
\nbput[nrot=:U]{\num{1.5} cm} 
\psSolid[object=plan, definition=solidface, args=theprism 0, action=none, name=theplane]
\psProjection[object=rightangle, args= h3 h1 h2, plan=theplane] 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, you misused `siunitx`. For example `\num{1.5} cm` must be changed to `\SI{1.5}{\centi\meter}`.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it a misuse as I switch up the units a lot and siunitx doesn't have all the units I use. I am interested in the ability to change the thousand separators and decimal symbols thus my use of \num{}